# How to prevent double border when using packed chain style in ConstraintLayout

Tags: java, android, user-interface, android-constraintlayout

I'm using horizontal chain with **packed**  style in a **constraint layout** that has a lot of TextView's (without a margin between them), all TextView's have a drawable rectangle border, and as a result each consecutive pairs have **"double"** border. Unfortunately, **ConstraintLayout** doesn't support negative margin. It took me more then two days to write all code. Please tell me how can i fix it (prevent a wide border)?
Any help will be blessed.
[image: con]

Comment: Why don't you just add margin to the start/end of each view?

Comment: @Francesc, i need them to be without a margin between them

Answer (score 0):

I Found a solution (not the best one, but i hope it's satisfy)..
We can run in a loop (when index i incremented by one) over all the **TextView's** on the line and use the function **setTrananaltionX** with **minus i (e.g -i)** as an argument. I suggest converting *index i* to DP units when using **setTranslationX** method. 
When we have finished running on all the TextView's, we will use **setHorizontalBias** method on the first item at the chain, with an argument that is bigger than 0.5 (i used 0.55) so the "packed" chain will go back to opposite direction (the opposite direction from the direction it "went toward when we have used **setTranslation** method)